# When will WSL2 to be generally available on Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Searching the internet shows that with Windows 10 version 2004, WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux, v2) is now generally available. I use it, and it's great.

All of the information *(as at September 2020)* that I've been able to find about Windows Server indicates that WSL2 is still only available in  insider preview builds. I've not been able to find anything out about when it might be available in a non-insider build of Windows Server

Has Microsoft made this information known? If so, which version of Windows Server would I need, and when would that be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can just confirm that WSL2 is part of the LTSC Windows Server Preview builds which are available in Core or Desktop Experience flavors.
The latest Windows Server Preview build 20287 is presenting itself as Windows Server 2022.

Just a note for those who would like to try WSL2.
The WSL2 bits are broken from build 20251 onward.
Look here to see how to download the last build where WSL2 works.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-insiders/wsl-2-not-working-after-installing-20262/m-p/2109063/highlight/true#M1601

Edit:
After 2020.1.31, there is no way to run wsl2 on Windows Server

Answer (score 5):

I feel that I cannot completely answer the question but that there is enough here to at least somewhat sort out the situation:

- WSL2 was first released as part of Windows 10 version "2004"
- Windows Server 2019 (current LTSC version) is version "1809"
- It was recently confirmed that [WSL2 will be backported to Windows 10 versions "1903" and "1909"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-support-is-coming-to-windows-10-versions-1903-and-1909/)
- The Windows Server Semi-Annual Channel (SAC), which I believe only carries the Server Core and Nano Server installation types, essentially matches the Windows 10 releases and does have the "2004" Windows version

If what you are looking for is support in Windows Server 2019 (Windows version "1809") there has to my knowledge been no word that WSL2 will be backported to this Windows version (for either Windows 10 or Windows Server).

For the LTSC channel I would expect (based on lack of other information) that it will not be backported to Server 2019, but that the next Windows Server LTSC version (which will be based on something newer than "2004") ought to have it. The popular assumption seems to be the next version will be named "Server 2022", but I'm not sure this is actually confirmed.

WSL2 in current Server versions in SAC, like Server Core "2004" or Nano Server "2004", may well already be a thing, assuming that WSL is installable in the Core/Nano Windows installations(?).

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm after installing one of the preview builds for Windows Server 2019 version 2004 that WSL2 is not supported and does not work.  I was working with the LTSC release of Windows Server.

Answer (score 2):

It is now supported on Windows Server 2019 (version 1709) and later.
See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server

Comment: Does this article talk about WSL1 or WSL2? It is not stated anywhere.

Comment: its WSL1 (only), and to be honest - I've followed these instructions as per the link, and its doesn't work!  The instructions aren't actually totally accurate (slightly contradict themselves in a few places - e.g. tells you to do wsl -l but this is a WSL 2 command that doesn't work in WSL1 ?!) and after trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows Server 2019 Build 1809 I got a nasty error 0x80073CF9, and couldn't even try Ubuntu 18.04 as it contains no appx file, so couldn't continue with the instructions.  Its all quite the pile of doggy doo!

Answer (score 1):

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-distros-are-now-supported-on-windows-server/ as of June 21st, 2022 states:

> You can now use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) 2 type distros on Windows Server 2022!